# Почему не устанавливаются куки при кросс-доменном запросе? [This set-cookie domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host url]

Tags: reactjs, cookie, cors, cross-domain, laravel7

В качестве сервера использую Open Server, в качестве фронтентда - React.js (с которого шлю асинхронные запросы на бэк), в качестве бэка - Laravel 7 (с пакетом Sanctum). Делаю авторизацию для SPA.

По идее, когда я отправляю запрос с фронта на бэк `http://localhost:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie`, то сервер должен установить куку для фронта, и куки действительно приходят, но не устанавливаются. В Chrome показывает предупреждение: `This set-cookie domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host url`.

[image: Скриншот с проблемой]

React.js с запросами axios:

```
  const onsubmit = e => {

    e.preventDefault();
    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
      
      axios.post(`http://localhost:8000/login`, {
        email: 'email@gmail.com',
        password: 'anypassword',
      }).then(response => {
      
        console.log(response)
      })
    })
    

    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/user').then(response => {
      console.log('User request: ' + response.data)
    })

  }
```

При клике на кнопку запускается `onsubmit()`.

Настройку Laravel Sanctum делал по документации.
Изменения в `cors.php, session.php, api.php, sanctum.php, Kernel.php и .env`. Laravel подключен к БД и в БД создан пользователь.
Показывать весь код не вижу смысла, так как сервер скорее всего работает правильно и кода придётся вставлять сюда много.

Кто сталкивался с ошибкой `This set-cookie domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host url` и как её решить?

Answer (score 0):

В `.env` файле установи

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:3001
```

`3001` - порт, на котором запущен react, в твоем случае 3001